# Cannot connect to repo with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been running a project for some months now using the same TortoiseSVN repository without much hassle, until now.

I need to add another box to the project but it seems to be impossible for TSVN to connect to the repository. This is the stuff I've discovered or tried out:

I have two client boxes: the "old" one and the "new" one...

1. Setting up and checking out a second folder on the "old" box works fine.
2. Browsing to the repo via Chrome/IE on the "new" box also works fine.
3. The browsers on my "new" box does not use a proxy (the same goes for the "old" box).
4. I am running TSVN 1.7.4, Build 22459 - 64 Bit on both boxes
5. When I attempt to connect to the repo from the "new" box using repo browser or checking out to a new folder I get this error message:

   Unable to connect to a repository at URL
   'https://(ip-address omitted)/usvn/svn/(project omitted)'
   OPTIONS of 'https://(ip-address omitted)/usvn/svn/(project omitted)': could not
    connect to server (ip-address omitted)
6. I have compared all TSVN settings between the "new" and "old" boxes and they all appear to match
7. According to the people running the server there's no certificates in use
8. The Windows firewall on the "new" box is down
9. I'm running both "old" and "new" box from the same network. The "old" is connected via WIFI however whereas the "new" one is on wire.

I'm at my wits end on what to check so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You may check in which network zone Windows 7 did put you into (I assume your box is a Win7), maybe your network zone is causing the trouble.

Comment: What about using the svn command line tools?  That would at least then determine whether it is tortoisesvn, or subversion in general.

Comment: boto: I'm not really sure how to check which network zone I am in (yes, I'm running Win7 btw). How is that done and how can I see if the zone is causing the problems?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to determine whether this is a problem with TortoiseSVN, your Subversion repository, or your network connection.

- First of all, check your URL. I never used [User-Friendly SVN](http://www.usvn.info/), so I don't know what it does to the Apache httpd configuration. However, the standard Apache configuration for multiple repositories is usually `http://<server>/svn/<module>` and not `http://<server>/svn/`***`usvn`***`/<module>`. Is that `/usvn/` directory suppose to be there?

  - By the way, how was Apache configured? Does User-Friendly SVN do that too, or does it merely allow you to configure the repositories? Are you using Visual-SVN, or did someone manually configure Apache httpd?
- If the URL is correct, try pinging your Subversion server. Can you ping it from your Windows box? If not, you have a network issue. For some reason that IP address isn't even reachable from your client box.
- Try opening a browser, and putting the URL of the Subversion repository into the window. This should work. If it does, the issue is probably with TortoiseSVN. Download a command line Subversion client, and see if you can checkout with that.
- Try using the same URL on another box. Can you checkout from there? If so, it points to a problem with the network.

Comment: If there is a network problem it doesn't stop a normal web browser from connecting to and browsing the SVN repository. It might still be some sort if comms issue though, assuming SVN uses a more complex protocol than the web browsers. But I have no clue as to what it could be.

Comment: @JonasRembratt - When you are using the http protocol in Subversion, it's pure `http`, so if a normal webpage can get through the network, from the server to the client, so can Subversion via Apache httpd. It's one of the reason why people use http with Subversion. Yes, Subversion is using a form of WebDav over http, but it's all http. (In theory, you could setup a router that can read the packets and filter out WebDAV http packets, but I've never seen that done.)

Comment: What if I cannot open the URL of the repository in a browser, even though I can ping the server found in that URL, I can connect to the repository from inside my workplace, our admin insists the URL should be reachable once I'm connected to our VPN (I am, as evidenced by being able to reach other internal sites) and none of my co-workers has any issues accessing the SVN repository while at home? Despite your helpful step-by-step guide, I am not sure what to conclude from these symptoms.

Answer (score 15):

Try clearing the settings under "Saved Data" - refer to:

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html

This worked for me with Windows 7.

Eric

Comment: That tips helped me in Windows 7 too.

Comment: Worked for me, people try to clear authentication data in tortoisesvn settings

Answer (score 5):

I've found that replacing the first part of the URL with IP address numbers instead of words worked for me.

For example use:

```
http://111.11.11.111/svn/Directory
```

instead of:

```
http://www.url.com/svn/Directory
```

Comment: +1 for the first person on this planet to actually show an example. The documentation does not mention you need to use http

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with exactly the same issue. I got my work laptop replaced and suddenly I stopped being able to connect to server. Strangely, initially I was getting errors only blocking me from committing, like:
Command              : Commit
Error                : Commit failed (details follow):
Error                : MKACTIVITY of '/svn/***/!svn/act/c511b853-23b4-db4a-8991-0bc689a63353':
Error                :  Could not parse response status line (http://****.****.com)
Completed!           :

When I moved to work in another branch (the SVN server was accessible with no issues for everyone on both branches, who has proper security), I started getting error like:

Command              : Checkout from http://***.com/svn/fineos***//trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included
Error                : Unable to connect to a repository at URL
Error                :  'http://****.com/svn/fineos***/***/trunk'
Error                : OPTIONS of
Error                :  'http://*****.com/svn/fineos***/***/trunk': could
Error                :  not connect to server (http://*****.com)
Completed!           :

Note: In each case, I could access repository through browser and it was working for everyone else, so obviously it wasn't network or repository issue.

This what worked for me was to uninstall Tortoise client, then remove Tortoise cache folder from Local and Roaming folders under C:\Users\*user*\AppData. 
Additionally I renamed TortoiseSVN node in Windows registry so the old configuration cannot be found.
Then after reinstallation, client connected to repo beautifully. I am not sure if both steps are required, maybe just changing registry will be enough, I will leave that to you to confirm.

Apologies for long response, but as I haven't seen response to this problem after googling for longer while, I thought that may be helpful for different cases.

Comment: This helped me, it was enough to delete the cache via the context menu  => Settings => Log Caching => Cached Repositories => Delete

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue while doing svn update.

The approach which worked for me is to rename C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\TortoiseSVN folder to TortoiseSVN_bkp folder and then tried svn update again. This time I was able to connect to repository and it got updated.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is case-sensitive.  Make sure that you're spelling it properly.  If it got renamed, you can relocate the working folder to the new URL.  See
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html

Answer (score 1):

Look into this as well:

**Issue:** After invoking SVN on the command line on a firewalled server, nothing visible happens for 15 seconds, then the program quits with the following error:

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'SVN.REPOSITORY.REDACTED'

svn: E730054: Error running context: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Investigation:** Internet research on the above errors did not uncover any pertinent information.

Process Tracing (procmon) showed a connection attempt to an Akamai (cloud services) server after the SSL/TLS handshake to the SVN Server. The hostname for the server was not shown in Process tracing. Reverse DNS lookup showed a184-51-112-88.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com or a184-51-112-80.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com as the hostname, and the IP was either 184.51.112.88 or 184.51.112.80 (2 entries in DNS cache).

Packet capture tool (MMA) showed a connection attempt to the hostname ctldl.windowsupdate.com after the SSL/TLS Handshake to the SVN server.

The windows Crypto API was attempting to connect to Windows Update to retrieve Certificate revocation information (CRL – certificate revocation list). The default timeout for CRL retrieval is 15 seconds. The timeout for authentication on the server is 10 seconds; as 15 is greater than 10, this fails.

**Resolution:** Internet research uncovered the following: (also see picture at bottom)

Solution 1: Decrease CRL timeout Group Policy -> Computer Config ->Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Public Key Policies -> Certificate Path Validation Settings -> Network Retrieval  – see picture below.

https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=470698

support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2625048

blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/05/14/3409948.aspx

Solution 2: Open firewall for CRL traffic

support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2677070

Solution 3: SVN command line flags (untested)

serverfault.com/questions/716845/tortoise-svn-initial-connect-timeout - 
alternate svn command line flag solution.

**Additional Information:** Debugging this issue was particularly difficult. SVN 1.8 disabled support for the Neon HTTP RA (repository access) library in favor of the Serf library which removed client debug logging. [1] In addition, the SVN error code returned did not match the string given in svn_error_codes.h [2] Also, SVN Error codes cannot be mapped back to their ENUM label easily, this case SVN error code E170013 maps to SVN_ERR_RA_CANNOT_CREATE_SESSION.

1. stackoverflow.com/questions/8416989/is-it-possible-to-get-svn-client-debug-output
2. people.apache.org/~brane/svndocs/capi/svn__error__codes_8h.html#ac8784565366c15a28d456c4997963660a044e5248bb3a652768e5eb3105d6f28f
3. code.google.com/archive/p/serf/issues/172

**Suggested SVN Changes:**

1. Enable Verbosity on the command like for all operations
2. Add error ENUM name to stderr
3. Add config flag for Serf Library debug logging.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by **David W.** "First of all, check your URL" - Our dns entry changed breaking all svn repo connections.  Connecting on ip instead of url as Wes stated worked - (now we have to fix our dns)

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced the same issue. I was trying to take svn checkout using repository URL consisting of DOMAIN NAME.  I tried to connect using IP address in place of DOMAIN NAME and I was able to take checkout

Answer (score 0):

Run ipconfig /flushdns from a command prompt.
Apparently some people seem to think I posted this answer for sheer fun. That's why they down voted my answer. Perhaps an explanation would help them.
When I used "SVN Update" it said it can't connect to the SVN repository although I could ping the server. After running ipconfig /flushdns the issue was fixed.